# Mass insert vs CTE insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert, common-table-expression

To preface this: I am running SQL Server 2005.

I am having a hard time deciding on which method to employ for an insert I am doing.

It started off as a very simple 100 line insert using for example:

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (1,'2',3,'4')
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (5,'6',7,'8')
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (9,'10',11,'12')
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) VALUES (13,'14',15,'16')
```

Now, I am a fan of readable and straight forward SQL, but it begins to urk me when the same code is repeated over and over and I was wondering if there was a better way of going about a repetitive insert such as this.

I have found CTE's and began to look up what I would need to do in order to work this in to my insert, to clean the code up a little bit. This has transformed my query in to the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN
;WITH CTEINSERT (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4)
AS
    (
        SELECT 1,'2',3,'4' UNION ALL
        SELECT 5,'6',7,'8' UNION ALL
        SELECT 9,'10',11,'12' UNION ALL
        SELECT 13,'14',15,'16'
    )
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4) 
    (SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
    FROM CTEINSERT)
```

So, this has made my query a little bit more dynamic (probably a bad choice of words) and has removed the repetition that was annoying me before, although it has some repetition to it, at least now the 'INSERT INTO' repetition has gone.

If I was running SQL Server 2008, I could obviously remove the repeating INSERT INTO that precede each line and just specify the values that I require inserting under the 1 INSERT INTO umbrella, but this is not an option.

My question is, does this make the query 'better' in any way aside from being a little easier on the eye (which is probably subjective anyway)? Is this any more productive or better/easier on the system then the original repetitive INSERT INTO query? I am just over thinking this and should go back to what I was doing previously?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the repetitive nature of the first example and avoid using a cte by using a **[Table Valued Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)**, which I think is more readable and easier to maintain than both of your examples:

<kbd>[Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75604/1)</kbd>

**MS SQL Server Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([COL1] int, [COL2] varchar(2), [COL3] int, [COL4] varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([COL1], [COL2], [COL3], [COL4])
VALUES
    (1, '2' , 3 , '4' ),
    (5, '6' , 7 , '8' ),
    (9, '10', 11, '12'),
    (13,'14', 15, '16')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

<kbd>[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75604/1/0)</kbd>

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
|------|------|------|------|
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |
|    9 |   10 |   11 |   12 |
|   13 |   14 |   15 |   16 |
```

Comment: Thank you pal. This was on my list of available options but wanted to avoid having to create a table to hold my information. I am starting to get the impression that this method would be the least taxing at least, although you still have to create the table which can look messy when we are talking 100-200 inserts that first need applying to the table. I will probably use this method and create the table before sending the code off for implementation to keep the SQL minimal.

Comment: You don't have to create that table, that was only done to illustrate how you could do this. You simply replace `Table1` with your actual table name. Or if you want to place data in a table before hand, use a #temp table.